# Orchestrate Sitecore deployments using Jenkins

Tags: .net, jenkins, sitecore, automated-deployment

We use Sitecore for our application and until now builds and deployments are manual. We have now started to use Jenkins for the build, but yet to figure out how to do deployments. The deployments are currently done by packaging using TDS and then deploying those to the Sitecore servers manually. Is there a way to use Jenkins to orchestrate this deployment? It would be much better if that could be achieved without having to install TDS on the Jenkins build agent. Any PowerShell scripts that could be used in Jenkins to achieve this or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the generated package automatically then there is a requirement to install Hedgehog's Sitecore Package Deployer module on your Jenkins Server. Installation and configuration guide can be found [here](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SitecorePackageDeployer).

Also some specific details about TDS configuration with Jenkins are described [here](https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/configure-tds-jenkins-server).